# Operations on selective rows on pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with phone calls, some of them are of zero duration. I want to replace them with int values ranging from 0 to 7, but every my attempt leads to errors or data loss. 
I wrote function:

```
def calls_new(dur):
    dur = random.randint(0,7)
    return dur
```

and I tried to use it like this (one of these lines):

```
df_calls['duration'] = df_calls['duration'].apply(lambda row: x = random.randint(0,7) if x == 0 )
df_calls['duration'] = df_calls['duration'].where(df_calls['duration'] == 0, df_calls.apply(calls_new))
df_calls['duration'] = df_calls[df_calls['duration']==0].apply(calls_new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc` to set the values only where duration is 0. You can generate all of the random numbers and set everything at once. If you want 7, the end of randint needs to be 8 as the docs indicate high is **one above** the largest integer to be drawn.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': [0,10,20,0,15,0,0,211]})

m = df['duration'].eq(0)
df.loc[m, 'duration'] = np.random.randint(0, 8, m.sum())
                                                #  |
                                                # Need this many numbers
```

---

```
print(df)
   duration
0         4
1        10
2        20
3         7
4        15
5         6
6         2
7       211
```